# Rasterize images for print manually

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design, print-production, digital-printing, bitmap

I'm trying to experiment with a thing. I have a laser printer that have both PCL and PS capabilities, however the image rendition is kinda poor, the print is very noisy.

I've seen some better printers out of there that are a bit upper level and use Fiery RIP. Fiery has tons of small options in order to control various function of the printer and also rasterize the data with some kind of stochastic screen and make the image grain less visible.

I just need to rasterize manually a CMYK image by rasterizing each channel and putting them back.

It is possible to do something like that with imagemagick command line tool ? It is possible to achieve that with photoshop or some kind of plugin that could do better work than plain ps in creating a stochastic screen ?

I assume that if I want to apply a profile conversion on a certain image I should do it before breaking down the image in the 4 bitmapped channels right ?

Thanks!